Cant seem to share a windows shared folder to my raspi5 keep getting this error
testkit@RASp5:~ $ sudo mount -t cifs -o username=Main_Link,pass=q&yLC0es9a //192.168.1.103/Remote_Access ~/Desktop/share

[1] 15535

bash: yLC0es9a: command not found

testkit@RASp5:~ $ mount: bad usage

Try 'mount --help' for more information.


try putting the password in quotes

I'd need to try it myself but here's what I think is happening
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=Main_Link,pass=q&yLC0es9a //192.168.1.103/Remote_Access ~/Desktop/share is read as 2 commands
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=Main_Link,pass=q is run first, put to the background and immediately, since you have an & yLC0es9a //192.168.1.103/Remote_Access ~/Desktop/share is run. Since there's no yLC0es9a command, and its trying to do that, you get the command not found, and since your mount stanza is truncated, it gets confused too.
I think there's two ways to deal with this. Considering you just put a secure password on the internet,changing it to one without an &  or characters with special meanings like " or % is a good idea
In addition to that, you can and should use a single quote around the password so it looks like
 sudo mount -t cifs -o username='Main_Link',pass='q&yLC0es9a' //192.168.1.103/Remote_Access ~/Desktop/share

This is generally good practice, and should work even if you have an & or such in your password.

sudo mount -t cifs -o username='Main_Link',pass='q&yLC0es9a' //192.168.1.103/Remote_Access ~/Desktop/share
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)

What ive tried:
Disabling windows firewall
Changing passwords/user
Making sure the folder is shared to everyone
Made sure i was discoverable on private network
Yes samba is installed
Yes cifs utils is installed
Ive also tried - sudo mount -t cifs -o username=Main_Link //192.168.xxx.xxx/Remote_Access ~/Desktop/share
And when prompted for the password there is no * symbols when i type in the password

Can you access the windows fileshare from another windows system?

Yes Im able to no issues, and from a mobile phone as well

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124342/mount-error-13-permission-denied might be a good place to start
